# Unable to compile with openssl c++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, openssl

I installed openssl through binaries and i have that exact files at that exact location.
But when compiling i face this error. any idea?

```
g++ main.cpp -I /usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/ 
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
main.h:4:25: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

---

update:

the below command did the job but i still face errors.

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/openssl/include -L/usr/local/openssl/lib main.cpp -lcrypto

/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

Any idea? :(

---

Solution :

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/openssl/include -L/usr/local/openssl/lib main.cpp -lcrypto -ldl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

> g++ main.cpp -I /usr/local/openssl/include

as the include directive is including the name of the subdirectory.

Note you will have to add the openssl library to link with. I am not familiar with it but something like `-lopenssl` and add a directory to be searched to locate it using `-L` option. The full command would be something like (as I am guessing the lib directory and name of library for openssl):

> g++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/openssl/include -L/usr/local/openssl/lib main.cpp -lopenssl

Comment: Thanks! now i solved it. but i have the following errors now : >>undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex'<<
 any idea? :D

Comment: @dupdupdup, was just updating my answer to address this.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libssl :( thanks for your help but i did that but i still cant solve it

Comment: >>/usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `dlopen'<<

Comment: `dlopen()` is defined in libdl.so, so you can add it by adding `-ldl` to your link command.

Answer (score 0):

no space between -I and the path.